# How we could configure icons image for a new document format in webtop?

Tags: documentum, webtop

I am using webtop 6.8.1 , CS 7.2.
I need to add one new Document format say .xyz. I have added it successfully.

But when such Document is listed, its icon is not getting shown correctly, while for other formats like pdf or gif it is showing correct icon.

do we need to add any gif in war file theme/icons folder?

Answer (score 0):

You can add custom icon for any format.

Icon images should be in GIF format and should be present in two dimensions: *16x16* and *32x32* pixels. Both GIF files should be located in *webtop/custom/theme/documentum/icons/format* folder and named using this pattern: `f_formatname_XX.gif` where:

- `formatname` - is a value of the `name` attribute of the `dm_format` object
- `XX` - is an image size with possible values *16* and *32*

For example we had on our past project icons for *Jasper Reports* and *InfoPath XML files* in this structure:

```
webtop
├── custom
│   └── theme
│       └── documentum
│           └── icons
│               ├── format
│               │   ├── f_jasperreport_16.gif
│               │   ├── f_jasperreport_32.gif
│               │   ├── f_xmlinfopath_16.gif
│               │   └── f_xmlinfopath_32.gif
...
```